# Incorrect "Notice: Undefined index" in PHP

Tags: php

I have a project that uses the codes bellow:

**Page 1:**

```
<form action="customersPrint.php" method="post" target="_blank">
   Customer's name: <input type="text" name="search1" /><br />
   <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

**Page 2 (customersPrint.php)**:

```
<?php
echo $_POST['search1'];
?>
```

The strange problem is that the code in page 2 works fine on local machine and a production server. But it returns the message below in another remote server:

> Notice: Undefined index: search1 in ...

This behavior is wrong. Because I've posted this parameter and also, it did not returned any similar message before.
What's the problem ?

**More information:**
Using the code below, I informed that page 2 says nothing has been sent to it:

```
if (isset($_POST['search1'])) echo 'Sent'; else echo 'Not sent';
```

Result was **Not sent**.

Also `var_dump($_POST)` returns nothing as result.

Comment: remove target="_blank" and then check

Comment: This is hard to tell with only that information.

Comment: It worked with `target="_blank"` without any problem

Comment: Put `if (isset($_POST['search1']){ ... }` around it. Your localhost doesn't show notices where your production server does. It is normal behaviour that you see this error message.

Comment: If it's set up exactly as you describe, it cannot cause that error. So I assume you're either paraphrasing the code, or the files on the remote server are out of date.

Comment: Try doing a var_dump of $_POST to make sure the information you're getting is what you think it is. As the old saying goes, when in doubt, dump it out.

Comment: @putvande the problem is what you mentioned. No variable don't be posted to the page 2.

Comment: @GordonM, `var_dump($POST)` returns an empty result

Comment: @MuhammadRashid then there's no data being posted to the form processing script.

Comment: @MohammadBagherSaberi Just a guess, would you add enctype to the form tag like this `<form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"...` and retry. If you have any other enctype set like `"text/plain"`, remove it.

Comment: @Jonny5, I did it. No change ... :(

Comment: @MohammadBagherSaberi Can you echo `ini_get('post_max_size');` Did any other posts work on that server, where you got the troubles yet? [Check out this](http://getluky.net/2009/02/24/php-_post-array-empty-although-phpinput-and-raw-post-data-is-available/)

Comment: there may be some apache mods (mod security) that could be causing issues with data being sent/received.  try changing the form method to `GET` instead of `POST` and check results on all servers.  also then change `$_POST` to `$_GET`

Comment: @binnyb, I've changed post to get and it worked well. What is this problem for ?

Answer (score 1):

Your localhost probably has all the `error_reporting` off where as your production server doesn't. So it is normal behaviour that you get this error message because `$_POST['search1']` does not exist when you first visit the page.

You can put a check around it to overcome this situation:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['search1'])) {
        echo $_POST['search1'];
    } 
?>
```

Also, I would turn off all error_reporting on your production website as it isn't very professional to show the errors to your visitors.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: I've tested it with `isset()` function. It says nothing has been sent. Whereas I've posted the form exactly

Comment: Did you send a value?

Comment: Yes I've sent a value

Answer (score 0):

If you are attempting to access customersPrint.php directly without submitting the form, then the `$_POST` variable is empty. The message you are receiving is not a fatal error, but just a notice that you are trying to output something that does not exist.

To fix this, check to see if the variable is set before the echo. For example:

```
echo (isset($_POST['search1'])) ? $_POST['search1'] : '';
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be a solution involving Mod Security.  Check out this link:  http://www.s2member.com/kb/mod-security-random-503-403-errors/

Try adding this to the root .htaccess file(taken from the above link):

```
# Mod Security v1.x.
# May work in .htaccess too, on some hosts.
<IfModule mod_security.c>
    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

# Mod Security v2.x.
# Will NOT work in .htaccess, use httpd.conf.
<IfModule mod_security2.c>
    SecRuleEngine Off
</IfModule>
```

Or if you have access to edit the httpd.conf file(taken from the above link):

```
# Mod Security v2.x only.
# Will NOT work in .htaccess, use httpd.conf.
<IfModule mod_security2.c>
    SecRuleRemoveById 960024 981173 981212 960032 960034
</IfModule>
```